# PHP test if operator exists?

Tags: php, testing, operator-keyword, exists

I needed to power something today and I've remembered that there is a new operator `**`, but only since PHP 5.6, which is, sadly, still not that spread.

So I wonder - is there some way to test if operator exists **not by testing PHP version**?

Obviously, there is no such function as `operator_exits(...)` and I couldn't find anything else.

Comment: As far as I know it isn't possible. Furthermore, if the operator does not exist the parser will just crash.

Comment: I doubt that `pow()` will be deprecated or removed, why not just use it?

Comment: @AbraCadaver of course I am not talking just about `pow()` but about any possible upcoming operators...

Comment: I heard some rumors this year that one could use some underlying C++ functions in PHP, this could have some answer in future :)

Answer (score 3):

No such function exists.

A function to check whether an operator exists or not only makes sense in a language which allows for `operator overloading` like `C++`. In `PHP` operators cannot be overloaded and the effort spend by the core team to develop such a function would never be worth the effort. We will just have to live with knowing which version supports which operators and work from there.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just check the [PHP version number](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpversion.php)? If it's under 5.6 have a fallback method.

Comment: a) I am looking for a way without that **b) if it is not there yet, obviously, you get parse error ;)**

Comment: @jave.web valid point about the parse error maybe have two versions check the version number and then  use an include to call the correct one?

Comment: Well, that is a solution :-D but sort of overkill :)